# In place upgrade from SQL Server 2005 Enterprise to 2008 R2 express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, upgrade, sql-server-2008-express

I couldn't find this anywhere, so i thought I'd ask here.  Can you do an in place upgrade from sql server 2005 enterprise to sql server 2008 r2 express?

The reason i'm asking is because i've got a 2005 instance that is being upgraded to 2008 r2 to reduce our licenses/costs (the database fits on 2008 r2 express), and i was jsut wondering if it'd be possible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar SO question:

[Importing Sql Server 2005 database into Sql Server express 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294136/importing-sql-server-2005-database-into-sql-server-express-2008)

Basically, you can bring a 2005 database into SQL Server 2008 R2 Express as long as it conforms to the Express limitations (10GB database).  However, the "in place" statement has me a bit confused.  There is no upgrade path for the server software itself from 2005 enterprise to 2008 r2 express.  The databases can upgrade but the software is different.  The good news is that you can install both 2005 and 2008 R2 Express on the same box if you really want (I would recommend against it though).